# RegEx problem or maybe another solution altogether?

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex, scrape

The problem I'm having is that I have a block of JavaScript I've successfully scraped out of a websites source and now I have to sift through to get the specific values I'm looking for.

I need to find `flvFileName` and get all the file names listed. In this case it's `'trailer1,trailer2,trailer3'`.

At first I started using regex to match the start and end tags and then match the file names and extract them to an array, but the problem is that there isn't always three videos in the list. There could be zero or more, so matching doesn't work.  Any thoughts on a way to approach this that won't make me continue to abuse my laptop?

```
... ,flashvars: {flvFileName: 'trailer1,trailer2,trailer3', age: 'no', isForced: 'true'} }); });
```

Comment: Is this an array with the last ']' missing or a string?

Comment: The sample JavaScript was really hard to read so I truncated it down to the section immediately before and after the target data. The original sample is available in the revision history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming it's a string (or you can get it to be a string)

```
p str.split(/flvFileName: '|', age/)[1].split(',')
#=> ["trailer1", "trailer2", "trailer3"]
```

This will split the thing in 3 parts:

- everything before *flvFileName: '*
- the good stuff
- everything after *', age*

Then split the good stuff on a comma.

Comment: Excellent answer, and I feel dumb for not suggesting this sort of string manip instead. I'm usually the guy who does that. +1

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [RKelly](http://rubyforge.org/projects/rkelly) to parse the JavaScript into Ruby for you.

Or, since Aaron seems to have [abandoned RKelly](http://tenderlovemaking.com/category/rkelly/), you could try its replacement, [Johnson](https://github.com/jbarnette/johnson).

Comment: I didn't need to actually make the JS to Ruby conversion.  I just needed to read the output and since the placeholders are rendered into JS when the page loads it was sufficient to just parse the HTML page.  I did read up on RKelly and Johnson.  I'm sure I'll revisit Johnson again in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

What if you do it in the old way?

```
start = string.index(flvFileName)
quoteStart = string.index("'", start)
quoteEnd = string.index("'", quoteStart)
trailersString = string.slice(quoteStart, quoteEnd)
trailers = string.split(",")
```

it's not beautiful, but it works. And you might need to do something special for the case when there's no trailer.

Comment: I edited your answer to remove the salutation. StackOverflow prefers we don't use salutations, valedictions or signatures in questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like: `\bflvFileName\s*:\s*("|')(?:\s*([^,\1\s]+)\s*,?)+(?<!,)\s*\1`

You might have to escape those backslashes; I don't know about Ruby, but you would in .NET. Note the backreference; that's the `\1` above. I'm using it to indicate that the filenames are wrapped in matching `"` or `'` characters.

All the `\s` might be unnecessary, but I'm leaving them in there to be thorough. I'm assuming there might be any amount of whitespace around the special characters (`:`, `"`, `,`, etc.). YMMV.

Also: `([^,\1\s]+)` might be too broad for describing filenames, depending on what you consider valid. You might want to use `((?:\w|\.)+)` instead.

Some reference information if the above is hard to grok: 
[**regular-expressions.info/reference.html**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)